# soap web service consume with ajax

Tags: ajax, web-services, cordova, soap

i've build a cordova application, my need is to call a soap webservice in javascript (Ajax or not) but i keep getting: (internal server error)

my code:

```
var soapMessage =
           '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
               '<soap:Body>'+
                   '<getList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">'+
                   '<M><H><WS>FrameWorkService</WS><F>getList</F><K>KeyElencoSoggettiTemplateInd</K><DS>ElencoSoggettiTemplate</DS><TB>SoggettiTemplate</TB></H><B><P><p_lingua>IT</p_lingua><p_opeId>NETA</p_opeId><p_socId>283</p_socId><p_eseId>1248</p_eseId><p_SogTemId></p_SogTemId><p_SogTemCod></p_SogTemCod><p_SogTemDes>A</p_SogTemDes><p_tipRic>I</p_tipRic><p_CodFisc></p_CodFisc><p_PartIva></p_PartIva><p_IscrCamCom></p_IscrCamCom><p_LocalitaDes></p_LocalitaDes><p_TipoIndId>SL</p_TipoIndId><p_CategoriaId></p_CategoriaId><p_TemplateId>1</p_TemplateId><p_Professionista>N</p_Professionista><p_PersonaFisica>N</p_PersonaFisica><p_NazId></p_NazId><p_ordinamento></p_ordinamento></P><NP>1</NP><RP>14</RP><TP>auto</TP></B></M>'+
                   '</getList>'+
               '</soap:Body>'+
           '</soap:Envelope>';


       $.ajax({
            //web service pubblico di prova
            url: ".../FrameWorkService.asmx",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "xml", 
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            headers: {
                SOAPAction: ".../FrameWorkService.asmx?op=getList"
            },
            data: soapMessage, 
            success: function(soapResponse){
                 alert(soapResponse);
              },
              error: function (request, status, error) {
                  alert(request);
                  alert(status);
                  alert(error);
              }
          });
```

Comment: Does this same envelope work when testing, say, from postman or anywhere else?

Comment: `.../` doesn't look quite right.

Comment: maybe i don't want to share my public webService???????

Comment: /fake instead would at least not look like an invalid url

Comment: yes it worked from another application we needed to do a mobile app

Comment: and so i get bad points for this ... and not writing this /fake ? ...

Comment: Why do you assume I downvoted you?

Answer (score 0):

In Cordova your page and JS will be loaded locally into the webview, essentially as a file:// URL... so, you need to set the full URL to your server in the $.ajax call's url setting.

If you are using Cordova 5, and this server is not SSL protected, you may also need to configure Cordova's Content Security Policy in the meta tags in your HTML.

Additionally if you are running iOS 9 you may also need to configure an App Transport Security exception for your server.  Both of those configurations are well documented here on Stack Overflow.